# Hashcode and Equals implementation

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

Consider the following `HashMap` implementation

```
HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(new String("ABC"), "Hello");
hashMap.put("ABC", "Hello");
System.out.println(hashMap.size());
```

How does the code return `size` as 1 with how internally this is evaluated? However, if I use `StringBuffer` instead of `String` code returns value as 2.
What is the reason behind this?

Comment: The `HashMap` first uses the object's `hashCode()` and then `equals()` to do the comparison.

Comment: If the `hashCode` method is equal, and the `equals` method returns true.

Comment: When I'm printing the hashcode for the two keys that I'm trying to put in the map, they are equal, which explains they'd be stored in the same bucket and .equals will be evaluated. But now I have a question how the hashcode evaluates as same when I'm using different String initialization methods.

Comment: try `new String("ABC").equals("ABC")` and `new StringBuffer("ABC").equals("ABC")` - the first statement should return true, whereas the second is false.

Comment: this question is titled as "Hasmap implementation", but actually you question is about the `equals()` and `hascode()` implementation in `java.util.HashMap`. Would you mind changing it?

Comment: The hashcode of a String is calculated based only on the characters in the String. It does not matter how the String object was created, both Strings contain the same characters.

Comment: the code won't compile if you try to insert a StringBuffer instance into  HashMap<String, String>, don't how you got the output as 2!

Comment: @nitnamby obviously i'd to make my map as HashMap<StringBuffer, String>, this would in that case return me value as 2

Comment: @PiyushWakhale well, StringBuilder doesn't override the default equals method of Object class, hence equals will always return false when two different instances are compared while inserting the keys in the HashMap.

Comment: @Alexander Sure Alexander, actually my question is how hashmap is internally implemented to handle this scenario. I'll correct that, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashMap`s use the `hashCode` method to determine the bucket and then `equals` to decide whether any existing object is the same as the one to be added. In your case both `"ABC"` and `new String("ABC")` will have the same `hashCode` and will be considered equal by `String.equals` so the two objects will be considered the same.

If you want this not to be the case then you could consider using an [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) which uses the object reference to compare for equality.

Comment: Be careful using IdentityHashMap with string keys. String interning may lead to unexpected behaviour!

Answer (score 3):

HashMap uses `Object.equals(other)` as the ultimate arbiter of whether 2 objects should count as "the same". With String, `equals` effectively compares the character contents of the String, so `"ABC".equals(new String("ABC"));` would return `true`.

StringBuffer, on the other hand, uses Object's default implementation of `equals`, which basically checks that both objects are *reference-identical* (i.e. they both point to the exact same memory address - this is what `==` does for Objects in java). Two StringBuffers constructed with two different `new` statements will never be reference-identical, and so never be `equal`. There's good reason for this: most of the time, we want an Objects's `equals` method to return the same answer for a given argument no matter when it's called. Since StringBuffer's contents can be manipulated, two buffers may have equal contents at one point in time, but then have different contents later, after one of them has been subsequently appended to.

The fact that StringBuffer is mutable probably makes it a bad candidate for use as the key of a map. You wouldn't be able to perform a lookup on the map unless you had the *exact same* StringBuffer that you originaly `put`. Conversely, if this behaviour is what you *want* for some reason, you can use [IdentityHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), which will always use an object's memory address to determine if it's equality to another, regardless of its type. Be careful with using IdentityHashMap with String keys though - because of [string interning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()), 2 equivalent strings constructed (from literals) in different places in the code *will* in fact point to the same piece of memory, so will be reference identical.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing type in `HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();`. If you want to create a map of `String, String` then you won't be able to create `StringBuilder`'s object as a key. If you want to support both then you might use `Object` instead of `String` as a key.
If you want to support `String` and `StringBuilder`, then your code will be

```
HashMap<Object,String> hashMap=new HashMap<Object, String>();
```

Below is the explanation for size difference.

"any value" is treated as an instance of `String` class. `StringBuilder` is different class than `String`. In your code, objects of the same class are being created as key, which results in same hashCode(see `hashCode()` function in `String.java`). However, `StringBuilder` used `hashCode()` from Object.java. Due to this they have different hashCode and are treated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap's put(K key, V value) method  first hashes to bucket via key.hashCode()%m and then iterates over the singly linked list of Map.Entry Objects to identify it 
the key exists via key.equals(k). If it finds a key it updates the value for that entry else it inserts the key in the front of the linked list

1) For StringBuffer case

```
    (i) new StringBuffer("ABC").equals(new StringBuffer("ABC")) is false
   (ii) new StringBuffer("ABC")!=new StringBuffer("ABC").hashCode() is false
```

This is because StringBuffer does not overide  and usesObjects equals(Object o) and hashCode() .
So they are two different entries in the map

2) For String Case

```
  (i) "ABC".equals(new String("ABC")) is true
 (ii) "ABC".hashCode()==new String("ABC").hashCode() is true
```

and so these two are a single entry in the map

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand what is hashmap, 
Equal and hashcode used to store and retrieve the objects from allocated memory locations. 
So in your case the key verified with content not with keyObjects reference since it is String. Even if you create String="ABC" literal or new String("ABC");
Equals method results true in this case so the the existing key replaced with new one. Its a basic concept of SET. HashMap uses SET as Keys. So when we try to add the new key which matches will replace the existing key by using equals method. 
For this reasons we should override the equals and hashcode methods properly. 
Rules:
If two objects are equal, then they must have the same hash code.
If two objects have the same hash code, they may or may not be equal.